# How can I rename a jsTree node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am not talking about `$("#demo1").jstree("rename",node)` which makes the node editable for the user. I am talking about the name being changed within the code. For example my nodes are all prefixed with a 2 digit number "[01]" so before I call `$("#demo1").jstree("rename",node)` I want to strip out the prefix, and put it back in once the user has finished editing. I have tried selecting "#nodeid a" but inside the hyperlink there is an ins tag and this gets replaced if i replace the URL contents. The documentation hasn't been helpful and I havent had much luck looking through the libraries code, can any help me? Chris

Comment: how about using using regex to separate the digits from the words

Comment: go on .. provide me with a jquery selector then and il see if it works..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The **recommended** method is to use [`rename_node`](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=rename_node)

```
$("#demo1").jstree('rename_node', node , text );
```

> [Please keep in mind](https://www.jstree.com/docs/interaction/) that **by default all modifications to the tree are
>   prevented** (create, rename, move, delete). To enable them set
>   `core.check_callback` to true

```
$('#demo1').jstree({
    'core': {
        'check_callback': true,
        /// rest of the options...
    }
});
```

**Rename your node (alternative, not recommended)**

```
$("#demo1").jstree('set_text', node , text );
```

**Debugging**

If you still encounter trouble, you can use this method to get the last error.

```
$('#demo1').jstree(true).last_error()
```

**For older versions (v1.*)**

```
$("#demo1").jstree('rename_node', [node , text] ); 
$("#demo1").jstree('set_text', [node , text] );
```

**See also:**

- [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxg8pyf1/) for the comparison and example of both methods.
- [Interaction with jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/docs/interaction/) (how to call API methods)
- API documentation of [`rename_node`](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=rename_node)
- API documentation of [`set_text`](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=set_text)

Comment: According to [the doc](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=set_text(obj%2C%20val)), `set_text()` is **used internally, please use `rename_node(obj, val)`**.

Comment: As mentioned by @jnoreiga : for 'set_text' method I have to change `rename_node` syntax to '$("#demo1").jstree('rename_node', [node ], text );` then it worked.

Comment: dom, You're right. The answer still reflected the solution at the time of the answer (for version 1.*). just updated this example to the recent versions of jsTree (v3.*), whch has some additional requirements regarding check_callback.

Comment: @Arend Thanks a ton..updated ans help me lot and finally check_callback work for me thanks again...

Comment: You can also use `id` string value instead of `node` object for first parameter. (I checked on v3.3.5)

Answer (score 5):

> I believe there is an syntax error with respect to the square braces "[" in the above answer. I use jsTree 3.0.4 and this is the correct syntax -

```
right -    $("#demo1").jstree('set_text',node,text);
wrong -    $("#demo1").jstree('rename_node', [node , text] );    

Example - 
$("#tree_3").jstree('set_text',"#idSelectorForNode" ,"NewName");
```

Comment: Thanks!! better -   $("#demo1").jstree('rename_node',node,text); ( because set_text is private method)

Answer (score 1):

You should turn on the switch to allow the rename operation, such as:

```
$('#container').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'check_callback' : function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
            // operation can be 'create_node', 'rename_node', 'delete_node', 'move_node' or 'copy_node'
            // in case of 'rename_node' node_position is filled with the new node name
            return operation === 'rename_node' ? true : false;
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for updating node text with `jstree` refresh:

```
$("#demo1").jstree(true).rename_node(node , "Renamed_Text");
```

Comment: This answer is very similar to [the most well received answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256060/14267427) to this question.