# Renaming a tree node dynamically outside of contextmenu in jstree

Tags: jquery, rename, jstree, treenode

I use the code below to successfully create a new tree node in jstree outside of contextmenu.  My question is how can you dynamically RENAME the text in a tree node in a similar manner outside of the contextmenu?  Is there a .jstree("rename" ....) function that can be called to accomplish this?  Much appreciated!

```
$("#RequirementsTree").jstree("create", null, "last", {"data" : "new_node_text",
                  "state" : "open",
                  "attr" :  { "id" : "new_node_id", "name" : "requirement" }, 
 });
```

I've tried the following:

```
        .bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
            ReqNode = data.rslt;

 $("#RequirementsTree").rename_node(ReqNode, "test");
```

That didn't work, however.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably better off sourcing the jstree site for a list of it's documentation, it will outline straight away if it's capable.http://www.jstree.com/documentation

Comment: I looked there and tried  $("#RequirementsTree").rename_node(ReqNode, "test");  That didn't work, however.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
$("#demo1").jstree('set_text', [node , text] );
$("#demo1").jstree('rename_node', [node , text] );
```

[JSTree Core Documentation...](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core)

[how-can-i-rename-a-jstree-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254735/how-can-i-rename-a-jstree-node)

Comment: I don't know what the deal is.  I tried both of those options you suggested and neither worked.  I know that I'm getting the li element since I can change the class on it, but that "rename_node" and "set_text" are just not working for some reason.  Should I be using something other than the li element for that particular node?

Comment: @TheDude "node" needs to be at the <li> level ID. Try to log $(node).attr("id") to see what value shows. Remember to pass over the # with the ID string. $("#demo1").jstree('set_text', ["#myID" , "SomeText"] );

Comment: I have to change the syntax to `$("#demo1").jstree('rename_node', [node ], text );` then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jsTree 1.0-rc3 version. The syntax below worked for me:

```
 $('#companyFields_tree').jstree('rename_node', '#0', 'testNewName' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The below suggestion by Mortalus didn't work for me.  Although it's my preference to stay within the confines of jstree specific code, I came up with a sort of jquery hack to get around the built-in "rename_node" and "set_text" methods since they weren't working for me.  I thought I'd post my answer here in case others have the same issue:

```
   $(Node).find("a").text("the_new_text_for_the_node_you_want_to_rename");
```

This works for me.  It basically grabs the anchor element below the li and sets the text for it.

Comment: it just shows for the time being .. when you actually go for edit again it sets the text to the default one .. have a look

Answer (score 0):

There's decision: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/cq9wzW9Ia3s

Shortly, by default jsTree prevents any changes in his tree, so you have to enable that:

```
$('#YourJSTree').jstree({ core: { check_callback: 'true' }, [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sentence works:
$("#demo1").jstree('set_text', node , text);